# Incorrect Tax Calculation

Tags: magento-1.7, tax

Following are my tax settings.

[image]

[image]

[image]

User belongs to Customer Group "EU-B2B VAT Free" but it is still getting charged 20% tax, whereas it should be charged 0% tax. I am not sure where the configuration is wrong or if there is any other issue. 
It will be helpful, if any one can guide towards right to resolve this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Issue was in the third party extension, 2 characters country code in Magento for Greece (GR) is different from initial 2 characters country code in VAT ID format for Greece (EL).

I have disabled the extension and recreate the extension's functionality using default Magento functionality and some customizations using my own custom module.